# Null is not an object RNGoogleSignin.SIgn_IN_CANCELLED React Native Expo Android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am gtting and Exception Error in React Native google signin module.
here is the compelte code snipt in the error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')
export const statusCodes = {
  SIGN_IN_CANCELLED: RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED,
  IN_PROGRESS: RNGoogleSignin.IN_PROGRESS,
  PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE: RNGoogleSignin.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE,
  SIGN_IN_REQUIRED: RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
};
```

in node_modules@react-native-google-signin\google-signin\src\GoogleSignin.ts

I am not able to find the solution.

Here is my code snipet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import SplashBG from "../icons/splashbg";
import Logo from "../icons/logo";
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

const GetLoginStatus = async () => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: '265662725956-ukku7c59o0afjqpig79bdcsrdnai4063.apps.googleusercontent.com' });
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log(userInfo);

}

const Splash = () => {

    const userstatus = GetLoginStatus();

    return (
        <>
            
            <View style={styles.BGContainer}>
                <Text>Login Screen</Text>
            </View>
            
        </>
    );
}

export default Splash;
```

My React Native Version
react-native@0.63.2
@react-native-google-signin/google-signin@7.0.0-alpha.3

I am getting this error in android. I havent checked on iphone but may be the same error is nowing on there too.

Please Help.

Comment: kindly check this git hub repo https://github.com/mohamed-ikram/google-sign-in. U need to do configure first when component mounted and later u need to call     const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently(); for ur use case

Comment: @ikmo I haved adedd the configuration and used signInSilently function but still getting same error

Comment: this is my repo i have used same package for sign in kindly check it https://github.com/ikmofem7/gmailsignup

Comment: @ikmo It is not react-native. I am using react-native 6

Comment: ever get a solution to this?